# Setting return value of an Instance method

Tags: objective-c, methods, return, instance

I know that Instance methods can return a value when they are done executing, but I do not know how to set & get that value, I know how to set the parameters but how do I set the return type of Method itself?

So, this is the Instance method implementation:

```
-(int) returnInteger: (id) anString: (int) anNumber{
```

to set it´s parameters i do:

```
 [self returnInteger: (id) returnNSString: (int) 100];
```

But how do I set the value of "returnInteger itself" I want to know how to set i both inside it´s implementation and when I call it (when it executes).

also - one more question

if I set it´s first parameter to be 100 inside the method, and when I call it I want to add 100 to it, how do i do that? i tried this -but did not work

```
[self returnInteger: (id) returnNSString: (int) + 100];
```

Comment: This makes very little sense; it seems to be founded on misunderstandings of how methods work. To get a value from a method, you call it, pass arguments, and have a `return` statement in its body. "value of the method itself" and "setting it both inside its implementation and when I call it" are non-sensical, and the declaration and calls are not doing what you seem to think they're doing. Perhaps if you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish we can be more helpful.

Comment: well.. since the return type of the declaration itself is (int) not (void) it should be able to return an integer number when done executing - I don´t have any "plan" I am just wondering why I haven´t seen this explained in any of my books on obj c

Comment: Or atleast assign the name of the method which return type is an integer an number like i do when passing it´s parameters arguments. What else is the point of assigning a datatype like int to an instance method return type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not really sure what you're asking, but here's an example that may be helpful.

```
@interface Juniper : NSObject
// Return type int, first parameter type NSString * and named s,
// second parameter type int and named i. Method's name is
// addNumberInString:toInt:
- (int)addIntInString: (NSString *)s toInt: (int)i;
@end

@implementation Juniper

- (int)addIntInString: (NSString *)s toInt: (int)i
{
    // Extract int from argument named s
    int intFromString = [s intValue];
    // Add that int to argument named i and end 
    // method, returning the result of addition
    return intFromString + i;
}

@end



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Juniper * j = [[Juniper alloc] init];
        // Execute the method, store the return value
        int result = [j addIntInString:@"100" toInt:15];
        // Display the return value so we know it worked.
        NSLog(@"%d", result);

    }
    return 0;
}
```